# What will happen when Eclipse IDE runs out of letters for their naming schema?

Tags: eclipse

So after Eclipse Zebra comes out in the next `foo` or so years, what will happen to Eclipse? I understand that probably only an Eclipse dev could really answer this, but I'm sure some of them are on here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Aardvark?

Seriously, it won't happen until the year 2029 and by then I'm sure they will have come up with a new naming scheme to entertain the masses.